# Does anyone have a GluonFX codebase with successful native builds after including application logging?

Tags: gluonfx

I started using LogBack logging library in my GluonFX app.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.6</version>
</dependency>
```

It's fine during `mvn gluonfx:run` but my build fails with `mvn gluonfx:build`.

Here's an excerpt of my stacktrace. I'll change logging libraries if someone can tell me what's working for them.

```
Exception raised in scope ForkJoinPool-2-worker-3.ClosedWorldAnalysis.AnalysisGraphBuilderPhase: org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser$BytecodeParserError: com.oracle.graal.pointsto.constraints.UnresolvedElementException: Discovered unresolved type during parsing: sun.reflect.Reflection. To diagnose the issue you can use the --allow-incomplete-classpath option. The missing type is then reported at run time when it is accessed the first time.
Caused by: com.oracle.graal.pointsto.constraints.UnresolvedElementException: Discovered unresolved type during parsing: sun.reflect.Reflection. To diagnose the issue you can use the --allow-incomplete-classpath option. The missing type is then reported at run time when it is accessed the first time.
```

Comment: Did you run `mvn gluonfx:runagent` before trying to build the native image?

Comment: That didn't resolve the stacktrace. I found this article and will try switching to java.util.logging - https://github.com/oracle/graal/blob/master/docs/reference-manual/native-image/Logging.md